# Php use header location to load new page in entire window within jquery tabs

Tags: php, jquery

I use Jquery tabs with in each tab a form. If the form is submitted it’s reloaded (after the actions in the database) in the tab so that not the whole page has to be reloaded. One of the forms has to link to a payment page if there has to be payed, so after some checks after a submit the payment page has to be loaded and the current page has to close. But if I use header-location the entire page Is loaded in the tab and i don’t want that….

Ho to use header-location from within the tab and load the payment page in the entire window (from PHP and not from Javascript because I can’t do the checks and vallidations)….

Answer (score 0):

Use [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) or check out the [jQuery $.ajax() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo "<script>
    window.location='?action=';
    </script>";
```